# Seeing an avatar in multiple views in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, avatar

I have a project that gives the user an option to upload an avatar. The upload works fine and, in fact, I can see the avatar in the root `/` of the project. However, when I navigate `/anything_else/`, my project can't seem to find the avatar.

Below is the relevant part of the model that handles the upload:

```
avatar = models.ImageField('profile picture', upload_to='static/media/images/avatars/', null=True, blank=True)
```

In my `user_base.html` template, I have the following line that shows the avatar

```
<img id="profile_pic" src="{{ user.avatar }}" alt="Profile picture" style="width:30px;height:30px;border:0">
```

So if I upload the picture `guitar.jpg` and go to `mysite.com/static/media/images/avatars/guitar.jpg`, it will be found.

However, if I navigate to `mysite.com/news/`, I still expect to have a viewable avatar, but instead I get a 404. This is because it looks for the image at `mysite.com/news/static/media/images/avatars/guitar.jpg`

I've heard of template inheritance, but I'm not really sure how to do this. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I solved it by changing

```
<img id="profile_pic" src="{{ user.avatar }}" alt="Profile picture" style="width:30px;height:30px;border:0">
```

to

```
<img id="profile_pic" src="/{{ user.avatar }}" alt="Profile picture" style="width:30px;height:30px;border:0">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is nothing to do with template inheritance, seems like maybe your `MEDIA_URL` does not start with `/`

That would mean you have a relative url (see [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2005079/202168))

also I think you need to use `<img src="{{ user.avatar.url }}">` in the template

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. I also tried adding a `/` to the `upload_to` and resulted in a crash.

Comment: sorry I meant `MEDIA_URL`, and no not to the `upload_to` because that's a path on disk not a url

Comment: `MEDIA_URL = ''`. My `media` directory is within my `static`, so I think it should be fine.

Comment: you're doing it wrong, you should set the `MEDIA_URL` properly so you don't have to add random stuff to your templates